# SQL Where COUNT() > 1

Tags: sql

I have this query here:

```
SELECT
    concat(dateSlot, ' - ', timeSlot),
    COUNT(concat(dateSlot, ' - ', timeSlot)) + 1 AS counter
FROM myTable
Group By concat(dateSlot, ' - ', timeSlot)
```

This gives me the concat of dateSlot and timeSlot and the number of times it appears in the table. Now I want to add a where clause saying, I only want the rows where counter is less than 70....how would I do this?

Comment: I suggest put your query in sub query and apply where filter where counter is less than 70. If it is as simple as that. Or u can use having filter in your single query

Comment: WHERE goes before GROUP BY; you probably cannot use the Alias at that point:  select blah, count(yoyo) +1 as counter from myTable WHERE count(yoyo)+1 < 70 GROUP BY blah ... could also use HAVING after GROUP BY, alias should work  ("having counter < 70")

Comment: But Gaurav, subqueries are notoriously slow ...

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT concat(dateSlot, ' - ', timeSlot), 
       COUNT(concat(dateSlot, ' - ', timeSlot)) + 1 AS counter 
FROM myTable 
Group By concat(dateSlot, ' - ', timeSlot)
Having COUNT(concat(dateSlot, ' - ', timeSlot)) + 1 < 70
```

Comment: invalid column counter :(

Comment: @user979331 I made a change to the query. Can you try now?

Answer (score 0):

add this clause to your query right after your AS clause

```
SELECT counter FROM myTable
```

Comment: invalid name counter :(

Comment: After as counter write SELECT counter FROM myTable